# Where to create your own file in Vapor?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8, vapor

I just tried to create a web app using Vapor, but when I tried to define my own variable/constant in my project, and write it in main.swift, the following error occurred.

```
let websiteURL = "http://localhost:8080" // in AppConstants.swift
let url = websiteURL // in main.swift
```

> Use of unresolved identifier: `websiteURL`

However, it seems that the `PostController` class defined in `Controllers` directory can be seen without any problems. I put `AppConstants.swift` in the same directory as `main.swift`, but it got the error above.

In traditional iOS/macOS app, which is the only project I have developed so far, if you just create any files in the project, they can be seen from anywhere in the project, I think.

So how and where can I create and define my custom file in Vapor?

---

### UPDATE

Here is my `Package.swift` file in my project:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "vapor_sample",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 0)
    ],
    exclude: [
        "Config",
        "Database",
        "Localization",
        "Public",
        "Resources",
        "Tests",
    ]
)
```

---

#### UPDATE 2

I found that for some reasons, the default files created by Vapor are named with directory suffix, like `Controllers/PostController.swift`, not `PostController.swift`. I tried moving `AppConstants.swift` under the directory, but it doesn't show its file name with the directory suffix. Is there anything related to it? I use Xcode 8.0.

[image]

Comment: @JoshCaswell Ah, sorry it was *unresolved identifier*, not *undeclared type*. But since the enum in *AppConstants.swift* gets me *undeclared type*, it would imply that the file is not seen in the first place.

Comment: What does your `Package.swift` look like?

Comment: @AntonBronnikov Updated.

Comment: The package seems ok.  If you put `AppConstants.swift` in the same folder as `main.swift` is, that is, `/Sources/App` it should make it's declarations "visible" to the rest of an app.  Check if there are syntax errors in that file, maybe.  Or try to do `swift build --clean` and then rebuild again.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov Thanks, I just found that executing *swift build --clean* and then build it again from within Terminal works, but it doesn't if you build and/or run it from within Xcode. Would you know anything peculiar about it?

Comment: Nothing specific that I know.  Just noticed that sometimes "weird" behaviour (like the one you observed) can occur due to glitches related to incremental build features.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov Since Kitura also released v1.0, I tried it. But it also had the same problem, so I assume the issue is related to Xcode and/or Swift, not Vapor.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode projects associated w/ SwiftPM and Server Side Swift generally tend to be a bit finicky. You should regen as often and as regularly as possible. Also cleaning and deleting derived data never hurts. Here's some situations you might want to regen:

- New File
- Changed File Name
- New Folder
- New Package
- Change Package Version
- Feel like it

Basically, anytime anything goes wrong in Xcode, and you don't know where to start. Clean, Delete Derived, Regen.